# Is there a way to detect and extract steganographically hidden data from a picture?

Tags: data-leakage, steganography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting Steganography in images](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2144/detecting-steganography-in-images)

Is there a way to detect and extract hidden data from picture which altered by steganography?

For example, If someone tried to spill confidential information through a picture which contain data attached on email from pc within a company, is there a way to detect the picture contains hidden information, and to extract it?

Comment: This presentation from defcon 19 might tell you some basics, at around 7:40 he shows one way of detection:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Ig2z9HPvBc&feature=plcp&context=C32c4a87UDOEgsToPDskJFh3jWTOjn0DU0VBRhJV6f It's not to advanced, but thought i'd throw it in there.