# Steganalysis of outgoing traffic

Tags: detection, monitoring, steganography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting Steganography in images](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2144/detecting-steganography-in-images)

Is there any commercial traffic monitoring systems that implements steganalysis and could issue a warning upon suspicious file transfer (i.e. upload of image)?

Comment: Not that I know of, but it doesn't sound very hard to do. There are plenty command-line tools which analyse images for steganography.

Comment: The techniques in the answers on that duplicate show many ways to do this. The fact it is outgoing traffic is mostly irrelevant - you just run everything through a steg scanner.