# Can we mask encrypted traffic to look like real traffic

Tags: end-to-end-encryption

Assumptions:

Some places ban or at least think about banning encryption.

Encrypted traffic can be easily spotted because it looks like nonsense (or something else?).

Question:

Suppose I put my encrypted traffic into a jpg and add a message "Hey John, look at my newest fractals." Would it still look like encrypted traffic?

Of course, that trick works only until someone knows it. But there are a lot more sophisticated methods thinkable (make numbers into words, let it look like (nonsense) text for example).

Is this realistic or am I missing something important?

Comment: Similar to: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93275/is-there-such-a-thing-as-public-key-steganography

Comment: Yes, that answers the question.

Comment: This will probably work if and only if your picture with encrypted data is really viewable by any picture-view-program without any error-message-popups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about stenography. Yes this is possible however if you are looking about doing this in an automatic fashion this becomes difficult because of communication of keys. This communication would easily be flagged and then blacklisted. Then you are back at square one. stenography is a heavily manual process, but is worth looking into and researching.