# Are there any tools to detect JPEG steganography?

Tags: python, steganography

I am looking for tools which can detect JPEG steganography for Windows or Linux.

All the projects I found are either so old that they are missing dependencies and there are no precompiled binaries.

stegdetect is so old and I can't seem to get it to install through any of the package managers of Linux.

Found this Python project: https://github.com/bannsec/stegoVeritas

However it uses PIL and Python3 and can't seem to install dependencies.

Aren't there any precompiled binaries for JPEG steganography detection available anywhere?

I only have zsteg but that cannot be used against JPEG files.

Comment: Assuming you don't mean JPEG 2000, the format is not ideal for steganography because it is lossy (hiding data in LSB encoding doesn't work, for example). You're much more likely to find something hidden in PNG.

Comment: I agree with @forest PNG is the way to go for steganography.

Comment: See also https://security.stackexchange.com/q/2144/165253

Comment: @forest If you can make everybody else believe that JPEG isn't suitable for steganography it will make JPEG more suitable as your steganography is less likely to be discovered. Hiding data in the least significant bit will work even in JPEG, but it will be a lot more complicated. And you probably need to use the highest quality setting for your JPEG files to make the steganography less obvious.

Comment: @kasperd Perhaps I should have said that it's incapable of reliably containing more than a nominal amount of hidden information, whereas PNG can contain quite a lot.