# What can a jpg with a small width and height hide?

Tags: steganography, image

I'm new to cybersecurity. I am participating in the [cybersec challenge](https://www.challengecybersec.fr/).
I have [an image](https://www.challengecybersec.fr/chat/public/uploads/evil_country_landscape.jpg) to analyze. This image is small but super heavy. I thought that there was a message hidden behind but all my attempts at steganography have been unsuccessful.

Do you have any advice? I am only looking for tips as it's a challenge :)

I looked thoroughly at [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2144/detecting-steganography-in-images). But most links are down.

Comment: 2 of the 5 links are down. The rest of the information in the answers provide useful info. The point is that there are tons of tools to detect steganography. You have also not provided any focus to the question but to point you to generic resources.

Comment: Here's a hint for you. **Look at the sizes!** The image is a tiny image but the file is huge. Standard Steg techniques will not handle this degree of disparity in size. You can't interleave 300 meg of data into a few K of picture. Think *Old School* simplicity, not fancy Steg.

Comment: Your new question is a little like asking "how long is a piece of string?"