# How to make this script run from image?

Tags: web-application, xss

I'm testing my application for security vulnerabilities. I've inserted javascript in a gif and uploaded it into the application. The application loads the image in `<img>` tag. The script gets executed only if the image is given as source in `<script>`. Is there any other way to load the script in the image?

Comment: Do you have control over the mime type or extension?  Or do you just have the ability to upload an arbitrary file that is then treated as an image / GIF? Any validation on the fle?

Comment: No, I don't have any control over its type. I just upload the file. The application does an extension check as well as a content type check before it accepts the file.

Comment: XSS can occur if user does a right click over the image, and "open image in a new tab" or so. In such case, the GIF will be opened in a new tab, and if it's containing HTML code, then browser might sniff it as HTML and interpret it in the new tab. To avoid this, `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` + HTTP response `Content-Type: image/gif` + putting images on a separate domain + setting some strict `Content-Security-Policy: default 'none'` can mitigate the attack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, it has been possible, such as the [GIFAR malware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIFAR) case from over a decade ago.

But as of now with modern web browsers, there is no way. It has been patched to prevent polyglot images from being executed at will. `<img>` will only read and output the image as an image, regardless of the Content-Type of the page itself (it used to take precedence).

However, you might want to know that it might be possible to do an XML injection using an `svg` file. XSS will not be possible as long as you stick to the `<img>` tag, but XXE can occur.

Comment: And even with SVG or XML-based image format (if there are others than SVG, which I'm not aware of), then browser might still not execute the dynamic javascript content

Answer (score 1):

Its difficult in current browsers to get a browser to execute javascript when its served up in another mime type / embedded in an image tag.

IE may be vulnerable if you allow access to the image directly (try the direct URL) and aren't leveraging the "nosniff" headers: "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" header

But there are a lot of things you need to worry about if allowing untrusted content to be uploaded.  See [Does X-Content-Type-Options really prevent content sniffing attacks?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12896/does-x-content-type-options-really-prevent-content-sniffing-attacks) for a good summary of the issues with allowing file uploads to your site.

Best practice - if you can, serve user content from a separate domain.