# How confident is MIME blacklisting on a proxy server?

Tags: proxy

We are blacklisting a number of MIME types on our proxy server so users can't download certain file types, for example, executables.

Could it be possible that somehow, a malicious server can trick a user (maybe through script exploits or drive-by) to browse and download a malicious executable, bypassing the blacklist? Let's assume the proxy server only allows HTTP traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On older browsers, the answer is *yes, this kind of attack is possible*, due to some browsers' support for MIME content-type sniffing.  You can Google for content-sniffing attacks and you'll find a lot more details.

To defend against it, set the header `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` (only supported on IE8 and IE9, I think), and make sure to serve a valid content-type in the `Content-Type:` header.  Those will disable content-type sniffing on many browsers (on IE8, IE9, and non-IE browsers, at least).

See also
[Using file extension and MIME type (as output by file -i -b) combination to determine unsafe files?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/7506/971),
[Does X-Content-Type-Options really prevent content sniffing attacks?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/12896/971),
[What are the security risks of letting the users upload content to my site?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/503/971),
[How can I be protected from pictures vulnerabilities?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/8587/971),
[Is it safe to serve any user uploaded file under only white-listed MIME content types?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/11756/971),
[MIME sniffing protection](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/3129/971),
[Why should I restrict the content type of files be uploaded to my site?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/11548/971).

I also recommend that you serve user-uploaded content from a separate domain, to sandbox the user content and ensure it cannot tamper with your content.  For instance, you might host your content on `www.example.com` and host user-provided content on `uploads.example.com`.

---

Update: I just learned that setting the `Content-Type` and `X-Content-Type-Options` headers are not enough for security.  Apparently, [Flash ignores the Content-Type header](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/42904/971), which could allow loading a malicious SWF, which can then do everything you'd do with a XSS.  (Sigh, stupid Flash.)  Unfortunately, no amount of headers can stop this attack.  Consequently, it appears that the only safe solution is to host the user-uploaded content on a separate domain.

Comment: Thanks for the comment D.W.. However in my case I have no control over the web server; I'm on the client side downloading files. But I have a browsing proxy that can be configured to blacklist certain MIME types. While content-sniffing remains a potential attack vector, I was wondering if it's possible for a browser (through malicious servers or client-side scripts) to download executables that somehow get through the proxy blacklisting.

Comment: Interesting, most MIME questions listed are also from those new to this site with low rep.  Perhaps the search functionality is confusing users MIME with S/MIME results

Comment: @lithium, I believe the answer is yes, it is possible for a malicious executable to get past your proxy, despite the blacklist of MIME types.  An attacker can create malicious content that is served as (say) `Content-Type: text/plain` but that some IE browsers will treat as some sort of malicious executable (or other dangerous MIME type).  The attack exploits IE's MIME content-type sniffing algorithms.  See the links in my answer, and especially the research paper by Barth et al. for a definitive treatment.

Comment: @D.W. Thanks, actually it was first through the searches I learnt about the content sniffing exploit. But I think what I was getting at was a malicious script could well get a browser to `code`GET`code` an executable from a server that, say, specifies the MIME type as `code`text/plain`code`, save it somewhere, and run the executable from the saved location, and there's nothing the proxy can do about it.

Comment: @lithium, yes, good point.  As far as I know, that is a realistic risk as well.