# Flash ignores Content-Type header, allowing XSS?

Tags: web-application, xss, same-origin-policy, flash

I recently read that the Flash plugin ignores the `Content-Type` header in certain circumstances.  In particular, you can give Flash a URL, and the Flash plugin will happily fetch the content at that URL and load whatever it receives as a SWF file, with the permissions of the site that the content was loaded from — even if the response comes with a `Content-Type: text/plain` header (or any other `Content-Type` at all).  The `Content-Type` header can indicate that this is not a SWF file, and Flash will still load this as a Flash file.  The content that's loaded doesn't even have to be a valid SWF file; it just has to start with a valid SWF file, and the Flash plugin will ignore any additional cruft that follows.

The source for this claim: [http://50.56.33.56/blog/?p=242](http://bit.ly/1xJGUCt)

If this is true, this is not good.  It means that my site is vulnerable to XSS, if there is any page where the attacker can control the start of the page.  It means that my site can be vulnerable even if I carefully set the `Content-Type` header correctly everywhere.  It means that the standard defenses against XSS when serving user-uploaded content are not sufficient.

For instance, if you want to allow the user to upload an arbitrary text file and serve it to anyone who asks, a standard approach is to make sure to set `Content-Type: text/plain` on the response.  It's widely believed that this is sufficient to be secure.  If I understand this vulnerability correctly, this practice is not secure: a malicious user can upload a malicious text file containing the contents of a SWF file, and then cause it to be executed by the Flash plugin, creating the moral equivalent of a XSS vulnerability in the site.

This has me a bit gob-smacked.  Is it really true?  Does Flash really have this vulnerability?  Has Flash been patched to fix this?  Are there any mitigating factors?  Is there any clean server-side defense to prevent this kind of attack?

Answer (score 3):

> It means that the standard defenses against XSS when serving user-uploaded content are not sufficient.

The standard defence against XSS when serving user-uploaded content is to serve it from a different address (ideally different domain and IP address completely, but a subdomain stops *some* attacks at least). That is, you allow it to fall victim to XSS, but isolate it so that such a compromise doesn't hurt the main site.

> For instance, if you want to allow the user to upload an arbitrary text file and serve it to anyone who asks, a standard approach is to make sure to set Content-Type: text/plain on the response. It's widely believed that this is sufficient to be secure

A lot of things that are completely untrue are widely believed.

`Content-Type`/`Content-Disposition` was never a sufficient defence, in the face of type sniffing (from both the browser and plugins). `text/plain` is the worst possible case: because it was (inadvisably) included as a default `Content-Type` in Apache, most browsers will completely ignote that type in favour of sniffing magic words from the start of the file.

> Has Flash been patched to fix this?

No. Though there's a worse one with `crossdomain.xml` syntax being buried inside other filetypes and loaded through `getPolicy()` that has been mitigated somewhat.

> Are there any mitigating factors?

The kind of interaction allowed from Flash under its own variant of the Same Origin Policy doesn't necessarily allow you full scripting into the JS origin. But yeah, it's pretty bad.

Java and Silverlight have similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Content-type is not intended to provide security; it is merely a suggestion to the browser as to how a web page should be interpreted in the absence of other information.

There's nothing stopping your web page (e.g. as part of a flash object) from loading page content decorated with whatever content type you like and interpreting it as something else. This can happen with a flash object, or via systems like XmlHttpRequest. (If you run an XHR query and `eval` the result, or blindly insert the result into the page, you'd be just as toast)

Put another way, the content type tells the browser what basic behavior to give a piece of content. If your client code, be it JavaScript, Flash, or what have you, says to do something different, then that something different is going to happen.

Comment: *"There's nothing stopping your web page from loading page content decorated with whatever content type you like and interpreting it as something else."* - I think you've missed the point. Modern browsers *do* respect the Content-Type header. If the response has `Content-Type: image/gif`, browsers won't treat it as HTML and run Javascript found in it *with all the privileges of the origin from which it was loaded*. (Old versions of MSIE violated this, but that's fixed in modern IE's.) `Content-Type:` *is* a critical security feature; sadly Flash doesn't respect the same rules that browsers do.

Comment: (cont.) `eval` and XHR are not analogous, because they don't involve the browser executing the content with the privileges of the origin that the content was loaded from.  If a page `eval`s some XHR'ed content, that's not the browser doing it, that's the page making an explicit trust decision.  That's different from what's going on with Flash.

Comment: @D.W.: "Giving flash a path" to execute is the same thing as `eval` -- it is something the web page asked the browser to go fetch and said "this is a SWF, please interpret it that way for me".

Comment: It's not the same thing.  When `evil.com` can tell Flash to go fetch a resource from `good.com/foo.csv` and have Flash treat the response as a SWF file and execute it *with the privileges of `good.com`*, that's a very bad thing.  `eval()` is not comparable; `evil.com` can use `eval()` to ask the browser to fetch a resource from `good.com/foo.csv` and then ask the browser to treat that as Javascript and execute it, but the browser will give it *the permissions of `evil.com`*.  Do you see the difference?  The difference is huge!

Answer (score 0):

X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff might just be your friend. It instructs the browser not to guess the content-type but stay true to what the server says.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that Flash pays any attention to `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`?  I've never seen any indication of that.  As far as I know, that header is supported only by ([some](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=security)) browsers, but not by the Flash plugin.

Comment: Nope, hence the use of the word "might".

Comment: Seems to me flash will only execute given the correct content-type these days (the frame with "Not Found" ran the flash)
http://research.insecurelabs.org/flash/